# change magento categories header color

Tags: magento2, category, css, header

i am using a magento theme and want to change the categories header color.
    is there any custom css code or method to change the same ?

( image attached )[image]

Comment: You should inspect with firebug or chrome dev tools and find the CSS classes related to these areas so you can update them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use category page body class for Header background color.
Please see below exmple:

```
.catalog-category-view .page-header {background-color: #ff5000;}
```

Or You can add custom class for category page to adding jQuery on list.phtml file

JS Content:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($) {
        $(function(){
            $("body").addClass("<?php echo __('your-custom-class-here');?>");
        })
    });
</script>
```